# ImportError: No module named 'twisted.scripts_twistw

Tags: python, flask, twisted

I try to use Twisted to run my Flask app.
but when I run this command below:

```
twistd web --wsgi myproject.main
```

in command prompt I got error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'twisted.scripts_twistw
```

does anyone anything about this?

PS: I'm using Anaconda 4.1.6 in Windows 10.

Comment: Did you install Twisted?

Comment: Yup. I've installed Twisted. but when I run it shows the error above. do you know what the cause?

Comment: set `PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib`

Comment: I've added the path but still not working.